# Moderation chat room

Tags: feature-request, chat

Can we create a moderation chat room, similar to [Superuser's](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=superuser.com) "Ask a Super User Moderator" room?
Reaching Arqade moderators (searching for deleted questions, problematic users, editing tags etc.) isn't currently easy - the only suitable [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=gaming.stackexchange.com) appears to be the general Arqade chat "The Bridge", which is more applicable for general gaming discussion and [averages at around 1000 messages per day](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/35/the-bridge).

Comment: Right, so why can't you use the existing room?

Comment: Mods are always present in the Bridge you just might need to ping them.

Comment: @badp: I don't want to interfere ongoing discussions. I'm almost certain that there would be no harm in creating such chat room, despite the negative response to this question.

Comment: @user598527 It'd require mods to be active in one more room, which is sometimes painful. If you need quick attention from mods, it should be worth interrupting current conversations anyways.

Comment: @BlueBarren: As far as I know the active moderators aren't displayed on chat pages, can be confusing for new users.

Comment: Mods are clearly labelled with a diamond beside their name, even in chat.

Comment: @BlueBarren: That's true, when they are active.

Comment: Even when mods are not actively chatting, there are usually high rep users in the bridge that can help with a lot of the community moderation activities.

Comment: I like to think of myself as a pretty active user and diligent reviewer... I can think of maybe one time where I wanted to actually speak to a mod directly instead of using the built-in moderation tools available to all users. I can't imagine this being so frequently necessary that a whole new chat room is required.

Answer (score 4):

There are other ways to discuss and get in touch with Moderators:

#### For Problematic Users/Posts

Firstly, if something is amiss with a post, or you're dealing with a 'problematic user' **Use a Flag**.

The problem with public chatrooms is that they're... well, *Public*. Flags are a *private* way to notify Mods of potential problems. Private for you, for us, (and for that 'problematic' user as well).

There's also finer grained control of flags (like the review system), so we can easily check up on previous interactions, unlike chat which requires a manual search.

#### For 'Editing Tags'

Just raise a meta question for these. Tags are community features and the wider community should have visibility of any proposed changes. So if you would like a synonym, rename, or something else, raise it here.

Check out the meta questions tagged with [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request), [tag-synonyms](/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) and [tag-merging](/questions/tagged/tag-merging) among others to give you some idea.

#### Searching for deleted questions

Yeah, this is the one scenario where pinging us in chat is one of the only viable options. If you just need us to extract some text from a deleted post it shouldn't be too much of a bother, so pinging us in The Bridge should suffice.

Comment: On SFF, we have a [community cleanup room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59281/sff-community-cleanup-room). Mostly it's populated with NAA/VLQ links, and Smokey reports. It's not very active (yay!), but it certainly has its uses. I'm guessing on a site as big as Arqade they would be a few people who would use one like this.